# Problems installing Haskell with Atom on a Mac

Tags: macos, haskell, installation, atom-editor, ghc-mod

I want to program in Haskell using Atom on a Mac. Therefore I installed the following packages in Atom:

```
haskell-ghc-mod
ide-haskell
ide-haskell-cabal
language-haskell
```

After that I installed the Haskell Platform 8.2.1 from here:
https://www.haskell.org/platform/#osx-none

This did not seem to work as I cannot compile and during every start of Atom there is this error message:

```
Haskell-ghc-mod: ghc-mod failed to launch. It is probably missing or misconfigured. ENOENT
```

Then I tried installing the necessary packages manually as described on https://atom-haskell.github.io/installation/installing-binary-dependencies/ which also failed (even unregistering failed):

```
Daniels-MacBook-Pro:ghc-mod-sandbox daniel$ cabal install ghc-mod stylish-haskell

Resolving dependencies...
cabal: Could not resolve dependencies:
trying: ghc-mod-5.8.0.0 (user goal)
next goal: base (dependency of ghc-mod-5.8.0.0)
rejecting: base-4.10.0.0/installed-4.1... (conflict: ghc-mod => base<4.10 &&
>=4.6.0.1)
rejecting: base-4.10.0.0, base-4.9.1.0, base-4.9.0.0, base-4.8.2.0,
base-4.8.1.0, base-4.8.0.0, base-4.7.0.2, base-4.7.0.1, base-4.7.0.0,
base-4.6.0.1, base-4.6.0.0, base-4.5.1.0, base-4.5.0.0, base-4.4.1.0,
base-4.4.0.0, base-4.3.1.0, base-4.3.0.0, base-4.2.0.2, base-4.2.0.1,
base-4.2.0.0, base-4.1.0.0, base-4.0.0.0, base-3.0.3.2, base-3.0.3.1
(constraint from non-upgradeable package requires installed instance)
After searching the rest of the dependency tree exhaustively, these were the
goals I've had most trouble fulfilling: base, ghc-mod, syb
Note: when using a sandbox, all packages are required to have consistent
dependencies. Try reinstalling/unregistering the offending packages or
recreating the sandbox.
Daniels-MacBook-Pro:ghc-mod-sandbox daniel$ cabal uninstall ghc-mod stylish-haskell
cabal: This version of 'cabal-install' does not support the 'uninstall'
operation. It will likely be implemented at some point in the future; in the
meantime you're advised to use either 'ghc-pkg unregister ghc-mod' or 'cabal
sandbox hc-pkg -- unregister ghc-mod'.

Daniels-MacBook-Pro:ghc-mod-sandbox daniel$ ghc-pkg unregister ghc-mod

ghc-pkg: cannot find package ghc-mod

Daniels-MacBook-Pro:ghc-mod-sandbox daniel$ cabal sandbox hc-pkg -- unregister ghc-mod

ghc-pkg: cannot find package ghc-mod

Daniels-MacBook-Pro:ghc-mod-sandbox daniel$ cabal install ghc-mod stylish-haskell

Resolving dependencies...
cabal: Could not resolve dependencies:
trying: ghc-mod-5.8.0.0 (user goal)
next goal: base (dependency of ghc-mod-5.8.0.0)
rejecting: base-4.10.0.0/installed-4.1... (conflict: ghc-mod => base<4.10 &&
>=4.6.0.1)
rejecting: base-4.10.0.0, base-4.9.1.0, base-4.9.0.0, base-4.8.2.0,
base-4.8.1.0, base-4.8.0.0, base-4.7.0.2, base-4.7.0.1, base-4.7.0.0,
base-4.6.0.1, base-4.6.0.0, base-4.5.1.0, base-4.5.0.0, base-4.4.1.0,
base-4.4.0.0, base-4.3.1.0, base-4.3.0.0, base-4.2.0.2, base-4.2.0.1,
base-4.2.0.0, base-4.1.0.0, base-4.0.0.0, base-3.0.3.2, base-3.0.3.1
(constraint from non-upgradeable package requires installed instance)
After searching the rest of the dependency tree exhaustively, these were the
goals I've had most trouble fulfilling: base, ghc-mod, syb
Note: when using a sandbox, all packages are required to have consistent
dependencies. Try reinstalling/unregistering the offending packages or
recreating the sandbox.
```

I already searched stackoverflow for answers but nothing really worked for me. Can anybody tell me what I am missing?

Answer (score 2):

I can advise you on one part of the problem. The error message from `cabal` is very confusing, but what it means is:

- `ghc-mod` does not work with a version 4.10.0.0 of the `base`
- The `base` library ships with GHC and cannot be changed
- GHC 8.2.1 ships with base 4.10.0.0
- Therefore: you cannot build `ghc-mod` with the version of the Haskell Platform you downloaded

You can work around this by downloading an older Haskell Platform (8.0.2). In my opinion: it's premature for the promoted Haskell Platform version to be 8.2.1.

Another approach is using Stack, which will manage the installation of GHC installations for you. In this case, running `stack install ghc-mod` *should* just work. But since you'll still be using GHC 8.2.1 from the Haskell Platform, it won't do you much good, since ghc-mod is tied to your GHC version.

Personally: I never had success setting up ghc-mod. I've also never used either Atom or VS Code, but I've heard people sharing good experiences with VS Code + Haskero, so if you're looking for an IDE-like experience, that may be something worth considering. I've switched over to using emacs+intero mode, which may be something to consider.

Here are some links that may be helpful on getting started with tooling:

- https://haskell-lang.org/get-started
- https://haskell-lang.org/intero

Comment: Thanks for the help. base-version 4.10.0.0 really seems to be the reason (it does say "base not < 4.10.0.0" in the error message but I somehow read <= 4.10.0.0 which I could not understand...) However, I even tried stack install - ghc-mod, but the result is the same, since ghc-mod will not be installed with base = 4.10.0.0. I could not find a way to uninstall and unregister it completely, though. Even stack clean did not work... :-(

Comment: After trying *stack install ghc-mod hoogle hasktags pointfree pointful cabal-install* (what they recommend in atom-haskell package) and adding the path that was mentioned during the installation */Users/daniel/.local/bin* to the path in atom it seemed to work, and there is no starting error message in atom any more. But still: clicking _Haskell IDE/Builder/build project_ in atom leads to: "ide-haskell-cabal ERROR no cabal found"... :-(

Comment: You may need to [configure settings](https://atom-haskell.github.io/core-packages/ide-haskell-cabal/) for the `ide-haskell-cabal` package.